# Xdocreport slow open generated .odt document with big table

Tags: velocity, libreoffice, xdocreport

I genarate .odt file using xdocreport and velocity. The generated file(9 pages, 48kb) is opened for about two minutes.

If saved this file and open again, it opening for about 2 seconds.

I can not imagine why it takes so long to open a document after it was generated. Is the table too large? Bad structure of the document?

Table with problem look like that(
Set the property to show the bounds of the table, even if there are none)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it's a problem with XDocReport? Perhaps you are loading complex data model with JPA or other framework and it takes time? I suggest you that you create a simple main with hard coded data model to test where problem comes from.

Comment: The problem arose because of another table. It was without borders and with lots of empty lines and columns.